# Storing data without making model in realm using swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, realm

Can I save data into the realm without making a model or object file and also retrieve from it using swift?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you explain what you mean when you refer to "the realm"?  When you say "without making ... [an] object file" do you mean that you don't want to write to and read from a file on disk?

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you want to or need to do this? Please update the question with additional info. Also, is the in regards to a local only realm or MongoDB Realm Sync?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. Realm models define the schema for that object type, and everything going into Realm needs to have a schema.

If you haven't gone over the docs, the Realm academy page could be a good place to start: [Realm Academy](https://academy.realm.io/posts/tim-oliver-swift-intro-to-realm/)

It's hard to say without more information in the original question, but if you want to skip defining the model because it's a one-off piece of data, you can consider storing it in UserDefaults. **But** there are caveats with that, and one of them is that values stored in UserDefaults are *not* secure. You should never store sensitive information there. Also, UserDefaults can only store certain data types, and storing too much data in UserDefaults can slow down the launch of your app.

[More info on user defaults.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults)

Comment: @maaztausif The Realm Academy is outdated at this point. See the [MongoDB Realm Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/) for an overview of MongoDB Realm and a tutorial. Also, storing large pieces of data is not a good use for User Defaults. It's really for storing data that fit its' name; *User Defaults*; the default background color or how numbers should be formatted; e.g. what the application uses as its *defaults*. And as this answer correctly states, it's not secure. There are usually much better options to store live application data but the question really needs more detail.